# Wordpress plugin : Following is not enabled

Tags: facebook, wordpress

I have a problem with facebook extension on Wordpress.
I have a red message on my website :

```
Erreur and when i click on : Following is not enabled for  https://www.facebook.com/Doccc.
```

When i check source :

```
<a class="pluginErrorLink" href="/plugins/error/api?code=100&amp;message=Following+is+not+enabled+for+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FDoccc.&amp;hash=AQBKvSIFcfJ0KB6H" target="_blank"><span class="fwb">Erreur</span></a>
```

My basic setting : http://hpics.li/172e2a2

Thank you for your help